# Unable to Run Puppeteer on AWS lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I am trying to run a small script in AWS lambda using AWSCloud9 but always get an error...!

```
2020-04-06 20:21:45.163 Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome: error while 
loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md
    at onClose (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:750:14)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:739:50)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at Interface.close (readline.js:409:8)
    at Socket.onend (readline.js:187:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1204:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Any Help??

Comment: Make sure you do headless: true

Comment: Still same error...!

Comment: You definitely won't get X11 errors with headless so check it again.

Comment: Tried many times...Even creating New AWSCloud9...Still not working

Comment: Actually that was my bad, you do need some X11 libs to run headless puppeteer.

Comment: I resolved it by using Node 10.x